# JAVA Getting a nullpointer exception in an "if" statement?

Tags: java

```
public void display(Date date) {
        boolean loop = true;
    System.out.println("Events on " + date.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
        while (loop) {
            Date tmp = schedule[i].nextOccurrence();
            if (tmp.compareTo(date) == 0) {
                System.out.println(schedule[i].nextOccurrence().toString());
            }
        }
        schedule[i].init();
    }
}
```

The above is supposed to print out an occurrence of an event if it falls on the date given to the method. The method nextOccurrence grabs the next occurrence of an event (if its weekly or daily). nextOccurence looks like this for a DailyEvent:

```
public Date nextOccurrence() {
        if (timesCalled == recurrences) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(startTime);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, timesCalled);
            timesCalled++;
            return cal.getTime();
        }
    }
```

I call schedule[i].init() to reset the number of times called to 0 (daily events have a limit of number of times they can be called, denoted as an int with the variable recurrences).

Basically, my problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException for this line:

```
if (tmp.compareTo(date) == 0) {
```

I've tried everything and I'm completely lost.
Any help would be great!

Comment: What happens if you are on the last occurence of schedule? What does `nextOccurrence()` return?

Comment: It seems like nextOccurrence has to be returning null, which happens when timesCalled==recurrences, just put a println before the if statement to find out exactly what is null.

Comment: if (timesCalled == recurrences) {return null;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method `nextOccurence` may return `null`, you need to check for that :

```
if (tmp != null && tmp.compareTo(date) == 0) {
```

Also, your `loop` variable is never set to `false` and will cause an infinite loop... And you call `nextOccurrence()` twice within your loop; is that desired?

You might consider redesigning your `getNextOccurence()` and have your `schedule` class implement an [iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) for your dates. This will change your loop with

```
Iterator<Date> iterator = schedule[i].occurenceIterator();
Date tmp;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   tmp = iterator.next();
   if (tmp.compareTo(date) == 0) {
      System.out.println(tmp.toString());
   }
}
```

which is cleaner than what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that your `nextOccurrence()` function is returning null. If it returns null, then you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use the `compareTo` function on that object.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you step through this in a debugger?

My guess is that

```
public Date nextOccurrence() {
    if (timesCalled == recurrences) {
        return null; // <<<<
    }
```

the line with '<<<<' is the root of the problem.